# DNS queries in Docker not hitting cache

Tags: docker, dns, google-cloud-dns, google-container-os

I'm using `Container-Optimized OS from Google` to run one of my Docker containers.
I have seen that amount of my DNS queries to Google Cloud DNS is really high (billions) and it super strange. I it only for internal DNS queries.

So after trying to perform `dig` from inside on of the containers I have seen it always performs a query to `nameserver` (from `/etc/resolve.conf` its Googles nameserver `169.254.169.254` )

So each query it still performs a query to nameserver without hitting the cache even once.

So I went and checked how it works on ubuntu instances and it works fine there.
Also checked deployments on kubernetes and they hitting cache from `kube-dns` as expected.

Is there is a way to solve it? I'm getting billions of queries instead of using the right TTL of DNS that getting ignored in this case.

Answer (score 1):

169.254.169.254 is not a nameserver. That is the virtualized IP address of the resolver which forwards requests to a DNS server.

If you want to cache queries, then you must configure a caching resolver inside your container. Look into products like dnsmasq.

Comment: google container os comes with `systemd-resolve` .
wasn't it suppose to share dns config of host with container and take advantage of it ? 
ubuntu comes with this functionality and it is not a special os for containers .

Comment: also google container os shares `resolved.conf` with the container. so it gets exactly same values inside container. so even if I will install dnsmasq , it would be tricky to take control of `resolved.conf` . 

I'm using `instance-templates create-with-container` for that docker image.

Comment: @MarkDavydov - The endpoint 169.254.169.254 is not the address of systemd-resolve or any other service running in Container OS. That is the address of the Metadata service. If your objective is a **caching** resolver, then you must configure one.

Comment: I didn't know about the origin of `169.254.169.254` at my `resolve.conf` file that's right.
But I still don't understand since when the default DNS caching of an OS is being ignored ? 
You are telling me that default behaviour of OS is to perform DNS query to nameservers on each request? What is TTL for then ?

Comment: @MarkDavydov What default DNS caching do you think is configured in a Dockerized application? There is none. TTL is one factor that a **caching** resolver uses to make cache decisions. Since your app is not configured with a caching resolver, requests are sent to the VM's resolver (169.254.169.254). Each request will be resolved by asking the upstream DNS server, which is Google Cloud DNS for private zones. For public zones, a full resolve will take place starting at the root name servers. If you want those requests cached, you must configure it.